# Check if a struct has struct embedding at run time

Tags: go

Let's say I have the following struct:

```
type Room struct {
  BaseModel
}

func main() {
  r := Room{}
}
```

Say elsewhere in the code I obtained an object r. It could be `Room` or something else. I want to check during runtime if r's class, in this case `Room`, has a struct embedding of BaseModel. Is that possible?

Comment: BaseModel is a 100% normal field of Room with name "BaseModel". reflect.TypeOf(r).FieldByName("BaseModel") will return that field or the zero Value if there is no such field. Anything you want to determine at runtime is done via package reflect and embedding produces normal fields. Pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: This question makes me think that you want to build some sort of inheritance and polymorph the Room into a BaseModel. Please note that Go does not support inheritance for good reasons. Consider using composition or interfaces that declare the behaviour that you are looking for. Even if Room **has** a BaseModel, it **is  not** a BaseModel, like you would expect with inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can check that in runtime by using reflection. Here's very simple example that uses `reflect.TypeOf` to print type of each field of struct `Bar` that embeds struct `Foo` and also `reflect.ValueOf` to print whether field is anonymous (`true`) or not - which is a good indicator of what you ask for:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    foo string
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
    bar string
}

func main() {
    test := Bar{}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(test)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Print(t.Field(i).Type, " ")
        fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(t.Field(i).Anonymous))
    }
}
```

Here is code on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/zNWxZUzq_RS

You don't ask what exactly you want to do with that information so pointing you to [`reflect` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) for more advanced use.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [`Anonymous`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField.Anonymous) field of `reflect.StructField`.

```
func embedsBaseModel(v interface{}) bool {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    if rt.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return false
    }

    base := reflect.TypeOf(BaseModel{})
    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        if sf := rt.Field(i); sf.Type == base && sf.Anonymous {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/-6flZcdSYwj

Comment: why not proposing the solution that consists of a private method on basemodel and an interface to type assert it ?

Comment: @mh-cbon if you believe it's a valid, if not the "best", approach to the problem you should post it as an answer. It may be that OP will prefer it over the alternatives, and if not OP then maybe some other devs might, at a later point in time.

Comment: @mh-cbon btw it just occurred to me that while your solution will work if the BaseModel is yours, it will not work if BaseModel is a 3rd party type.

Comment: yes i agree with that last statement. on the other hand, if you own the type, it will be a ton more efficient. anyway, i was not interested in answering that post. just hear your thoughts.